# Node Dependency Installation Error

Tags: python, c++, node.js, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to install a dependency using `"npm install blueimp-file-upload-expressjs --save"` command, but unfortunately I end up having an error stating that node-gyp rebuild has been failed. I have tried almost everything I've found over the internet such as;

- Installing Python 2.7
- Installing Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2012 Express version
- Installing node-gyp using `"npm install -g node-gyp"` command
- Installing Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express
- Installing Windows 7 64 bit SDK
- Setting Python.exe environment varibale

**To Mention**:

I have two versions of python installed, hence I went ahead and configured it using `"npm config set python /path/to/executable/python2.7"` command. I've read the [Node-Gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) github repository descritptions and followed all the steps. 
My operating system is windows 7 (64 bit).

Any idea regarding this issue is appreciated.

**Update:**

CMD error logs:

```
 $ if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "D:\Node-JS\node_modules\npm\b in\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) else (rebuild)
 gyp ERR! build error
 gyp ERR! stack Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\user\.node-gyp\0.12.4\x64\no de.lib'
 gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
 gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
 gyp ERR! command "node" "D:\\Node-JS\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\no de-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\node_modules\blueimp-file-upload-expressjs\nod e_modules\lwip
 gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.4
 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
 gyp ERR! not ok
 npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
 npm ERR! argv "D:\\Node-JS\\\\node.exe" "D:\\Node-JS\\node_modules\\npm\\ bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "blueimp-file-upload-expressjs" "--save"
 npm ERR! node v0.12.4
 npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

 npm ERR! lwip@0.0.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Failed at the lwip@0.0.6 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
 npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the lwip package,
 npm ERR! not with npm itself.
 npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
 npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
 npm ERR! You can get their info via:
 npm ERR!     npm owner ls lwip
 npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: What exactly is the error? Could you send some installation log files/terminal output?